# What write into sudoers file to allow USER1 execute specific command as USER2 without password

Tags: ubuntu, sudoers

What write into `sudoers` file to allow `USER1` execute specific command as `USER2` without password?

**Note that**:

1. I know that the file should be placed in `/etc/sudoers.d/USER1`
2. What permissions and owner should have this file ? `600` and `root:root` ?

Answer (score 1):

Tried looking in `man sudoers`? It has things you've probably never wanted to know, like:

> The sudoers grammar will be described below in Extended Backus-Naur Form
>        (EBNF).  Don't despair if you are unfamiliar with EBNF; it is fairly simple, and the definitions below are annotated.
>
> ...
>
> A user specification determines which commands a user may run (and as what
>        user) on specified hosts.  By default, commands are run as root, but this
>        can be changed on a per-command basis.
>
> The basic structure of a user specification is “who where = (as_whom)
>        what”.

So I think you might want a line like:

```
USER1  ALL=(USER2) command
```

Owner `root:root` looks good, with permissions `-rw-r--r--` (so 644)